# How to control two 12 V motors with the dual MAX 14870 Motor Drive Shield for Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

How to control two 12 V motors with the dual MAX 14870 Motor Drive Shield for Arduino?

I am a beginner and I need help on how to control two 12 V motors using the Pololu dual MAX 14870 Motor Drive Shield for Arduino Uno.

Answer (score 1):

I had attached the screenshot for this[image]

This picture tells you about the Arduino Connection with the with the SHIELD.

1. `EN (Enable Pin)` is used to enable and disable the motor drivers. As it is inverted `SET this PIN HIGH` will Disable the Motors and vice versa.
2. `DIR pinS` is used direction of rotation. It highly depends upon your connection, setting this `PIN HIGH LOW` will make the motor rotation from `CLOCKWISE & ANTI CLOCKWISE` or vice versa depends upon your hardware connection.
3. `PWM pins` are used to control the rotation speed of the MOTOR. `Driving PWM signal` on this pin will adjust your rotational speed. `MAX PWM frequency suggested is 50Hz`.
4. `Fault` is the `INPUT PIN to Arduino` with `ACTIVE LOW` signal indicating some kind of fault is there.

Comment: du i have to download and install a library for that shield.

Comment: No you can use simple digitalWrite and analogWrite instructions for handling all the pins.

Comment: thank you, you have been most helpful.

Comment: i'v been looking all over for help, i'm surprised there are not tutorials on how to use the Dual Max14870 Motor Driver Shield

Comment: You can use this [l293d with arduino](http://www.ardumotive.com/how-to-use-the-l293d-motor-driver-ic-en.html) for referral as they have similar properties. They are not exactly same but it will help you understanding with the CODE.